# creating object with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i need to create a form, which will create object which has another two objects as attributes, but those objects should be available from a dropdown list that contains templates of those objects.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :adresses, :profiles
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :city, :country
    belongs_to :user
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :nickname, :password
    belongs_to :user
end
```

tricky part might be, that User has no column 'address_id' or 'profiles_id', everything should go to the Profile and Address, which are being created in the same moment as the User (they have the same attributes as their templates)
I could really use some help, dont expext full code solution, but some hints would be nice

Answer (score 2):

Try this setup:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address
  has_one :profile

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :profile
  attr_accessible :adress_attributes, :profile_attributes
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :country
  belongs_to :user
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :nickname, :password
  belongs_to :user
end
```

See [doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)